# Should users be prevented automatically from posting a virtually identical question twice?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

Yesterday, a fairly new user asked a question in one of the tags I follow: [read excel file(which is in classpath ) via apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387365/read-excel-filewhich-is-in-classpath-via-apache-poi)

About 18 hours later, they asked pretty much the same question again: [read excel (which is in classpath ) via apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405638/read-excel-which-is-in-classpath-via-apache-poi)

Virtually the same title (modulo one word), almost all the text the same, code the same etc.

I flagged it as a duplicate, and a mod later came through and zapped it, but it was a non-zero amount of effort for the community

Could we not have the system automatically detect these kinds of very very similar duplicate questions from new/new-ish users, and tell them to edit their question rather than re-asking it?

Comment: One word : how?

Comment: This change would be a *huge* problem on Mathematics, given that users aren't too creative in naming their questions. I can't tell you how many times I've seen "Integration question" or "Probability" as a question title.

Comment: @HDE226868 Identical question *titles* are already blocked. This is why one sometimes sees "Probability question 3" and so on...

Comment: @Behaviour Thanks. Hmm, I suppose I'm misremembering, then.

Comment: @HDE226868, why would it be a problem if this change happened to (as a side effect) block questions with a poorly chosen super-generic title?  That sounds like a feature, not a bug, to me, especially if it provides feedback that prompts the asker to provide a better title.  That will make the site more useful to others and increase the chances that the question gets attention from folks who might be able to answer it.  If that was the side effect, it sounds like it'd be a win-win all around!

Comment: @D.W. I wasn't proposing blocking those titles - I thought it would be a *bad* thing to block them!

Comment: @HDE226868, I know.  I think you've misunderstood me.  I'm asking why you think it would be a bad thing to block super-generic titles like "Probability".  Maybe read my comment again?

Comment: @D.W. Definitely misread, thank you, though I think your revisions made it clearer. Anyway, come to think of it, it probably *would* be good to block them. You'd have to come up with a list of titles that wouldn't be suitable, but it would certainly work.

Comment: @JanDvorak How about saying that for people with fewer than 20 questions, you do a text similarity match on the title, and another on the body, using whatever your favourite similarity algorithm is, and reject if your new question is too close to any of your previous 20? (Picking 20 to reduce the amount of work needed on the server, and thinking that by 20 questions you've probably got the hang of the site)