# Rename [exact-duplicates] to [duplicate-questions]

Tags: feature-request, meta, per-site-meta, synonym-request

Going by [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/255554), there once was a time when what we now know as *duplicate questions* were called *exact duplicates.* Fortunately, this has been changed with exceptions to the tags on Meta SE and some site metas that have analogous tags. This is confusing as the scope of this tag covers all duplicates and not only exact ones.

I am aware that [duplicate-questions](/questions/tagged/duplicate-questions) is a tag synonym for [exact-duplicates](/questions/tagged/exact-duplicates), but this ends with the latter being enforced. I propose that this should be the other way round.

To add to the confusion, [there are questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245028/255554) which actually are about something that would deserve the name *exact duplicate.*

If such a renaming gets performed, this should also be applied to site metas which follow the main meta’s tag names – unless there is some site meta which uses [exact-duplicates](/questions/tagged/exact-duplicates) intuitively.

Comment: Yes for MSE, no for child metas.  Every site (and community) is different and so is their duplicate interpretation, so each child meta should decide for themselves what the appropriate "duplicate" tag should be

Comment: This is, hopefully, done now. Stuff broke a little, so if anyone finds something weird... feel free to ping a MSE mod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes a lot of sense.

Assuming we didn't break anything horribly (or at least failed to hide the evidence), its done for MSE