# Incorrect number of questions shown on tag mouseover

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

I recently answered [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189782/meta-duplicates-dont-require-an-answer-dont-suggest-there-is-one-when-that's). I also edited the question's tags from [exact-duplicates](/questions/tagged/exact-duplicates) to [duplicate-questions](/questions/tagged/duplicate-questions) as the former is now synonymized to the latter.

However, when mousing over the latter tag on the question itself, the popover shows that the tag has "14 questions" when the tag actually has 1,386 questions. In the revision history, I moused over both tags, and both show the same incorrect number.

Why is it showing the wrong number?

Comment: Looks like it may be a leftover of having swapped the master tag for the synonym, which we did in response to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245676/369802)

Answer (score 5):

At the time you asked this, the [duplicate-questions](/questions/tagged/duplicate-questions) tag *did* have only 14 questions in it. The rest still had [exact-duplicates](/questions/tagged/exact-duplicates).

[image: screenshot of the tag synonym list, showing that the bulk of the tags reside in the synonymized tag]

[As Tinkeringbell noted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323744/incorrect-number-of-questions-shown-on-tag-mouseover#comment1058219_323744), the master and synonym were [swapped a while back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245676/rename-exact-duplicates-to-duplicate-questions) - but the tags were never merged, thus leaving the bulk of the questions with the former master.

The question list for the tag presents all questions with either the tag *or any of its synonyms*, so it will tend to contain more questions than those with the tag, until all synonyms are merged.

This is clearly not an ideal situation, so I've gone ahead and merged the tags. The counts should now be sensible.