# Wrong questions count on tag popup if there are tag synonyms

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonyms

For instance, there are [2 synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/maintenance/synonyms) for the [maintenance](/questions/tagged/maintenance) tag. In such cases the count of questions shown in the popup (for any tag of 3) reflects only main tag usage:

> [image: tag popup]

But the [real question count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) is the sum of all: 28 + 19 + 39 = 86

> [image: real count]

Comment: I reported this before, and it was dismissed as by design: [Incorrect number of questions shown on tag mouseover](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323744/incorrect-number-of-questions-shown-on-tag-mouseover)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I hate such design!

Comment: You can file a feature request asking for the design to be changed

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog not today, need some time to rest. It would be great if you make that though (I mean FR, not to have a rest).